# How to display install page with the copy process as like in the image [NSIS script]

Tags: nsis

[image]

```
Outfile Test.exe
name "Test"

!include MUI2.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME 
Page instfiles Installer
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES 
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"


Function Installer

UserInfo::GetAccountType

pop $0

${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights to install application

    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"

    SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED

    Quit

${Else} 

    System::Call "kernel32::GetCurrentDirectory(i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}, t .r0)"

    CreateDirectory $3\pj

    CopyFiles /SILENT \Source\*.* \destination\

${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: with the above code Empty installation page displaying

Comment: Why censor the image? It just makes it harder to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two InstFiles pages in your script, don't do that. You are also calling a function at the start of the InstFiles page but you should not perform file operations in page functions.

Your file operation itself makes no sense, you should not copy based on the current directory!

The "copy" progress from your screenshot is actually extracting files from the installer and you get that for free in NSIS:

```
RequestExecutionLevel Admin
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
!include MUI2.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES 
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function .onInit
UserInfo::GetAccountType
pop $0
${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights to install application
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
    SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
SetOutPath "$InstDir"
File /r "c:\myfiles" ; This will display the extract progress
SectionEnd
```

If you actually want to copy files instead of extracting then you can just remove the `/SILENT` switch to display the normal Windows copy dialog.

If you must copy files with output similar to extraction you must manually walk the source directory with `FindFirst`+`FindNext` and use `DetailPrint`+`CopyFiles /SILENT` for each file...